# Multiple roots nginx

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to have a suburl that point to a different root? For example:

```
www.domain.com/ -> /home/ubuntu/project1
www.domain.com/project2 -> /home/ubuntu/project2
```

I have this configuration at this moment but I'm getting a 404 when resolving `domain.com/project2`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /home/ubuntu/project1;

    location /project2 {
        root /home/ubuntu/project2;
        index index.html;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the difference between `root` and `alias` directives. If your folder name and URI prefix are equal, just use `root /home/ubuntu;` instead of `/home/ubuntu/project2;`

Answer (score 0):

It's because nginx will append the uri to `root` directive. 
In your example config, accessing `domain.com/project2` would try to look for a file named `project2` in `/home/ubuntu/project2` which is not found and return 404. 
To solve your problem, try using [alias](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) directives.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /home/ubuntu/project1;

    location /project2 {
        alias /home/ubuntu/project2;
        index index.html;
    }
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```